# Unable to display an input from a user using Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and the .NET Code / VSCcode.
Currently using VSCode to run and build C# codes.

I am unable to take user input using `Console.ReadLine()` after declaring a particular variable to hold it. The terminal generates this error code at the end of the program:

> The program '[4544] forth.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

```
using System;

namespace forth
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.WriteLine("This is the first program we are trying to build");
            var  name = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name, "you successfully entered a name");


         Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name, "you successfully entered a name");

         Console.WriteLine("you can press enter to exit the program");

         Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

Output "please enter your name" and displays "Hello + the user's name"
The program should exist afterwards

Comment: `code 0 (0x0)` means "there's no more code to run, the program exited successfully". It's not clear what happens or what you expect to happen

Comment: Is this .NET Core on a Linux machine, or is it .NET Framework on Windows?

Comment: because your program exited, like the message said...

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the comma after name to inside the string, and appending the second string to the first:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + ", you successfully entered a name");
```

At the moment you will be using the WriteLine(string, string) overload, when I think you just want WriteLine(string)

Comment: Note that "The program '[4544] forth.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." isn't an error - this is what happens when a command line application finishes and you have not set an exit code

Answer (score 1):

When you created your project you picked the wrong type. You need to pick "New Console Application".

Right now you are building a library and a library does not have a `Main` method. Well, it can have, but it's not called. So create a new project, pick the correct type and copy your code over.